# Aspectj in maven with spring works in IDE but not in production

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, aspectj

I am using intellij IDE with maven and spring. I am trying to enable the aspectj caching, which required to enable the LoadTimeWeaving to be enabled too. I am able to compile, run and test my web application through the IDE, but when I package it through maven it gives the following exception

```
            2015-01-14 12:08:34.658 ERROR 5896 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplicat
    ion               : Application startup failed

    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean wit
    h name 'loadTimeWeaver' defined in class org.springframework.context.annotation.
    LoadTimeWeavingConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [
    public org.springframework.instrument.classloading.LoadTimeWeaver org.springfram
    ework.context.annotation.LoadTimeWeavingConfiguration.loadTimeWeaver()] threw ex
    ception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [org.s
    pringframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTrans
    former(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start y
    our Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:org.springframework.ins
    trument.jar
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instant
    iateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:597)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
    Factory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:10
    94)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
    Factory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:989)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
    Factory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
    Factory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getOb
    ject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
    y.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBe
    an(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean
    (AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.
    preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finish
    BeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refres
    h(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
            at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationConte
    xt.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.
    java:691)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java
    :320)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java
    :952)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java
    :941)
            at pts.web.Starter.main(Starter.java:80)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner
    .java:53)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Facto
    ry method [public org.springframework.instrument.classloading.LoadTimeWeaver org
    .springframework.context.annotation.LoadTimeWeavingConfiguration.loadTimeWeaver(
    )] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLo
    ader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader] does NOT provide a
    n 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver
     or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:org.springfr
    amework.instrument.jar
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy
    .instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:188)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instant
    iateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:586)
            ... 23 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [org.springframework.boo
    t.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTr
    ansformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual m
    achine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:org.springframework.instrument.jar
            at org.springframework.context.weaving.DefaultContextLoadTimeWeaver.setB
    eanClassLoader(DefaultContextLoadTimeWeaver.java:91)
            at org.springframework.context.weaving.DefaultContextLoadTimeWeaver.<ini
    t>(DefaultContextLoadTimeWeaver.java:67)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.LoadTimeWeavingConfiguration.l
    oadTimeWeaver(LoadTimeWeavingConfiguration.java:81)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.LoadTimeWeavingConfiguration$$
    EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$412ffa57.CGLIB$loadTimeWeaver$2(<generated>)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.LoadTimeWeavingConfiguration$$
    EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$412ffa57$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f927f664.invoke(<genera
    ted>)
            at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.j
    ava:228)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$Bea
    nMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.LoadTimeWeavingConfiguration$$
    EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$412ffa57.loadTimeWeaver(<generated>)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy
    .instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
            ... 24 common frames omitted

    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner
    .java:53)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creati
    ng bean with name 'loadTimeWeaver' defined in class org.springframework.context.
    annotation.LoadTimeWeavingConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested ex
    ception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Facto
    ry method [public org.springframework.instrument.classloading.LoadTimeWeaver org
    .springframework.context.annotation.LoadTimeWeavingConfiguration.loadTimeWeaver(
    )] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLo
    ader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader] does NOT provide a
    n 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver
     or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:org.springfr
    amework.instrument.jar
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instant
    iateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:597)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
    Factory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:10
    94)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
    Factory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:989)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
    Factory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
    Factory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getOb
    ject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
    y.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBe
    an(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean
    (AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.
    preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finish
    BeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refres
    h(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
            at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationConte
    xt.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.
    java:691)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java
    :320)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java
    :952)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java
    :941)
            at pts.web.Starter.main(Starter.java:80)
            ... 6 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Facto
    ry method [public org.springframework.instrument.classloading.LoadTimeWeaver org
    .springframework.context.annotation.LoadTimeWeavingConfiguration.loadTimeWeaver(
    )] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLo
    ader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader] does NOT provide a
    n 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver
     or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:org.springfr
    amework.instrument.jar
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy
    .instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:188)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instant
    iateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:586)
            ... 23 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [org.springframework.boo
    t.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTr
    ansformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual m
    achine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:org.springframework.instrument.jar
            at org.springframework.context.weaving.DefaultContextLoadTimeWeaver.setB
    eanClassLoader(DefaultContextLoadTimeWeaver.java:91)
            at org.springframework.context.weaving.DefaultContextLoadTimeWeaver.<ini
    t>(DefaultContextLoadTimeWeaver.java:67)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.LoadTimeWeavingConfiguration.l
    oadTimeWeaver(LoadTimeWeavingConfiguration.java:81)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.LoadTimeWeavingConfiguration$$
    EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$412ffa57.CGLIB$loadTimeWeaver$2(<generated>)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.LoadTimeWeavingConfiguration$$
    EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$412ffa57$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f927f664.invoke(<genera
    ted>)
            at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.j
    ava:228)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$Bea
    nMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.LoadTimeWeavingConfiguration$$
    EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$412ffa57.loadTimeWeaver(<generated>)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy
    .instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
            ... 24 more
```

I have used following configuration for spring

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
                                DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan
@PropertySource("classpath:config/${ENV:dev}.properties")
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@Import(value = {IntegrationConfiguration.class, LoadTimeWeavingConfiguration.class})
@EnableMetrics
@EnableCaching(mode=AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving = EnableLoadTimeWeaving.AspectJWeaving.ENABLED)
```

My pom.xml has the following dependencies

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>pts</groupId>
  <artifactId>pts-web</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
    <start-class>pts.web.Starter</start-class>
  </properties>


  <dependencies>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
      <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.togglz</groupId>
      <artifactId>togglz-spring</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.togglz</groupId>
      <artifactId>togglz-spring-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.togglz</groupId>
      <artifactId>togglz-servlet</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.togglz</groupId>
      <artifactId>togglz-junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.ryantenney.metrics</groupId>
      <artifactId>metrics-spring</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
      <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
      <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.codahale.metrics</groupId>
      <artifactId>metrics-annotation</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
      <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.trecloux</groupId>
        <artifactId>yeoman-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <configuration>
          <filesets>
            <fileset>
              <directory>yo/dist</directory>
            </fileset>
            <fileset>
              <directory>yo/.tmp</directory>
            </fileset>
          </filesets>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <webResources>
            <resource>
              <directory>yo/dist/</directory>
            </resource>
          </webResources>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
          <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
          <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>


        </configuration>


      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>

      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Can anyone give me and idea why its working through the IDE but not independently after packaging? I am running it with the following command,
java -DENV=production -jar /home/pts-java/pts-web.war --server.port=8080

Comment: what is the JRE version in dev and prod ?

Comment: jre1.8.0_25, as the dev and prod machines are same for now, I dont think the versions would be different. I am just running it from command prompt from the same machine

Comment: For starters stop mixing spring versions. Spring Boot uses 4.0 or 4.1 whereas your aspects are 3.1 never mix versions of a framework. YOu seem also to have to much dependencies those which are already managed by spring (spring-tx for one, spring-security-web is part of the spring-boot-starter-security depednency which I would suggest adding).

Comment: Next to that judging from the error you aren't running the application in the same way in your IDE as you do in your production env. You say you want loadtime weaving, then why do you have compile timeweaving setup in your maven pom?